# On start scan BluetoothLeScanner app crashes and no results are displayed

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ble

The error message I see is:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(java.util.List, android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings, android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)' on a null object reference at com.example.drodo.diamondbeacons.BleDevicesActivity.startScanning(BleDevicesActivity.java:91) at com.example.drodo.diamondbeacons.BleDevicesActivity$1.onClick(BleDevicesActivity.java:68). Error in line: mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(buildScanFilters(), buildScanSettings(), mScanCallback);

Here's my code:

```
public class BleDevicesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar bleToolbar;

private static final String TAG = BleDevicesActivity.class.getName();

private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 5000;

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner;
private ScanCallback mScanCallback;
private TextView deviceName;
private TextView deviceAddress;
private Button scanDevicesBtn;
private Handler mHandler;

public void setBluetoothAdapter(BluetoothAdapter btAdapter) {
    this.mBluetoothAdapter = btAdapter;
    mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ble_devices);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    bleToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ble_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(bleToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Ble Devices Nearby");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    deviceName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.device_name_text);
    deviceAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.device_address_text);
    scanDevicesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_devices_btn);

    scanDevicesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startScanning();

            Snackbar.make(v, "Scanning for BLE Devices Nearby", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

public void startScanning() {
    if (mScanCallback == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting Scanning");

        // Will stop the scanning after a set time.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stopScanning();
                Toast.makeText(BleDevicesActivity.this, "Scanning Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        // Kick off a new scan.
        mScanCallback = new SampleScanCallback();
        mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(buildScanFilters(), buildScanSettings(), mScanCallback);

        String toastText = getString(R.string.scan_start_toast) + " "
                + TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(SCAN_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + " "
                + getString(R.string.seconds);
        Toast.makeText(BleDevicesActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(BleDevicesActivity.this, R.string.already_scanning, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Stop scanning for BLE Advertisements.
 */
public void stopScanning() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Scanning");

    // Stop the scan, wipe the callback.
    mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
    mScanCallback = null;

    // Even if no new results, update 'last seen' times.
    //amAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Return a List of {@link ScanFilter} objects to filter by Service UUID.
 */
private List<ScanFilter> buildScanFilters() {
    List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<>();

    ScanFilter.Builder builder = new ScanFilter.Builder();
    builder.setServiceUuid(BleConstants.Service_UUID);
    scanFilters.add(builder.build());

    return scanFilters;
}

/**
 * Return a {@link ScanSettings} object set to use low power (to preserve battery life).
 */
private ScanSettings buildScanSettings() {
    ScanSettings.Builder builder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
    builder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER);
    return builder.build();
}

/**
 * Custom ScanCallback object - adds to adapter on success, displays error on failure.
 */
private class SampleScanCallback extends ScanCallback {

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);

        for (ScanResult result : results) {
            String device_name = result.getDevice().getName();
            String device_address = result.getDevice().getAddress();

            deviceName.setText(device_name);
            deviceAddress.setText(device_address);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        try {
            ScanRecord scanRecord = result.getScanRecord();

            assert scanRecord != null;
            byte[] manufacturerData = scanRecord.getManufacturerSpecificData(0x0590);

            assert manufacturerData != null;

            double lightValue = Double.parseDouble(Arrays.toString(new byte[]{manufacturerData[0]}).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
            double tempValue = Double.parseDouble(Arrays.toString(new byte[]{manufacturerData[1]}).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
            double batteryValue = Integer.parseInt(Arrays.toString(new byte[]{manufacturerData[2]}).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
            int alertPresses = Integer.parseInt(Arrays.toString(new byte[]{manufacturerData[3]}).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));

            Toast.makeText(BleDevicesActivity.this, "LIGHT: " + lightValue + " %", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(BleDevicesActivity.this, "TEMPERATURE: " + tempValue + " \u2103", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(BleDevicesActivity.this, "BATTERY LEVEL: " + batteryValue + " Volts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(BleDevicesActivity.this, "ALERT PRESSES: " + alertPresses, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            String error_message = e.getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(BleDevicesActivity.this, "Error: " + error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
        Toast.makeText(BleDevicesActivity.this, "Scan failed with error: " + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
}
```

What could be causing the crash?

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
```

is initializing your `BluetoothLeScanner` instance to `null`.

The method `getBluetoothLeScanner` returns non-`null` only when Bluetooth is *actually switched on* on your device. As a result, you should call `getBluetoothLeScanner` *each time* you need to use the scanner (rather than storing a reference), and aggressively check the result is not `null` before using it. If the result is `null`, you probably need to prompt the user to enable Bluetooth before continuing.

In your specific case, you should:

- remove the `mBluetoothLeScanner` field;
- replace the line `mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(buildScanFilters(), buildScanSettings(), mScanCallback);`
   with something like

  ```
  BluetoothLeScanner scanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
  if (scanner != null) {
      scanner.startScan(buildScanFilters(), buildScanSettings(), mScanCallback);
  } else {
      // Device Bluetooth is disabled; check and prompt user to enable.
  }
  ```
- replace the line `mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);`
   with something like

  ```
  BluetoothLeScanner scanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
  if (scanner != null) {
      scanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
  } else {
      // Device Bluetooth is disabled; scanning should already be stopped, nothing to do here.
  }
  ```

Comment: What I would change to my code then? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated with some concrete suggestions. Showing how to check Bluetooth state and prompt the user to enable is out of scope for this question, but here are [some slides that should point you in the right direction](https://speakerdeck.com/stkent/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-top-tips-for-the-tricky-bits-v4-codemash?slide=28) :)